# I want to Explore the whole character of a string like C Language in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying a lot to do this but it does not return false flag when input was not number at all. whats the right way to explore each and every character in JAVAScript Like C Language .

```
var phonenumber = document.forms["signupform"]["phonenumber"].value;

var numberok = true;
var numberstr = "0123456789";

for(var i=0;i<phonenumber.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<numberstr.length;j++){
        if(phonenumber.charAt(i) != numberstr.charAt(j){
            numberok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(numberok == false ){

    alert("Enter Correct Phone Number");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code is basically saying "each character in the phone number must match every digit at once otherwise the whole thing fails". I don't think that'd work in C language either.

Comment: Then what the right code To reach in every character of a String in Javascript. I want to know that very well ... Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up your code to only use a single loop and use the `indexOf` method to see if the digit was in your `numberstr`.

In real code there are much better ways to see if something is a number, but I wanted to keep the methods you were using here, since you specifically asked about examining every number in the string.

```js
var phonenumber = "9994";

var numberok = true;
var numberstr = "0123456789";

for (var i = 0; i < phonenumber.length; i++) {
  var char = phonenumber.charAt(i);
  // In modern browsers could also be written as:
  // var char = phonenumber[i];

  if (numberstr.indexOf(char) === -1) {
    numberok = false;
    break;
  }
}


if (numberok) {
    alert("Phone number is good");
} else {
  alert("Enter Correct Phone Number");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do validate your phone number by regex:

```
if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(phonenumber)) { // only digits

    numberok = true;
}
```

If you want to determine the length of `phonenumber`:

```
if (/^[0-9]{7}$/.test(phonenumber)) { // only 7 digits

    numberok = true;
}
```

As result you can make your code more compact:

```js
var phonenumber = '503002010';//document.forms["signupform"]["phonenumber"].value;

if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(phonenumber)) {

    alert("Enter Correct Phone Number");
    //return false;
}
else {

    alert("Yay!");
    //return true;
}
```

Comment: Why we need to use that =>  **/^[0-9]+$/**
I want to know details about this kind of usage.
can you give me a useful link of this (  **/^[0-9]+$/**  )  kind of topics ?

Comment: This is regular expression. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Lets analyse our expression: from start `^` to end `$` string must contain only digits from 0 to 9 `0-9`. Digits count must be equal to 1 or more `+`. If you want to validate fixed count of digits, just replace `+` with this `{7}` (7 digits for example). If you want to determine an interval (of count) try this: `{5,10}`.

Comment: Thanks a Lot . 
This is Seriously Helpful answer what i want to Learn. 
**Thanks** Again :) .

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="tel" pattern="\d+" name="phonenumber" />
```

No JavaScript necessary.

Comment: but if i want to do that with Javascript then what i do programmatically  ??

Comment: Why would you want to do it the hard way when there's an easy way right here??

Comment: I just want to Learn.
Thus i can work with String and Character and perform any operation with string by filtering character of that string. 
I want to learn more about the Character operation as i do in C before . :)

Comment: Part of learning how to use the tools you have, is learning when NOT to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution which is very similar to C code and very fast:

```
var phonenumber = document.forms["signupform"]["phonenumber"].value;

// Phone number is not okay if string length is 0.
var numberok = phonenumber.length ? true : false;

// Test code value of each character in phone number string on being a
// digit in character range '0' to '9' having in Unicode table (and in
// all code pages) the code values 0x30 (decimal 48) to 0x39 (decimal 57).
for(var i=0;i<phonenumber.length;i++){
    if((phonenumber.charCodeAt(i) < 0x30) || (phonenumber.charCodeAt(i) > 0x39)){
        numberok = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(numberok == false ){
    alert("Enter Correct Phone Number");
    return false;
}
```